# Схемы в postgres

Tags: postgresql

По умолчанию используется схема public. Но как я понимаю, я могу создать еще кучу других, и выбрать по умолчанию какую либо другую, и вообще обращаться к любой схеме. Но для чего этот функционал нужен?

Comment: чтобы одна бд могла обслуживать не одно приложение, например

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну вот в mysql я допустим создал бд one и two, в postgre это выглядит как one.public two.public. То есть я могу сделать one.someschema. Но чем это лучше, чем сделать бд three.public?

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/ddl-schemas

Comment: "Базы данных" в mysql - это схемы в терминологии postgresql. А "Базы данных" в Postgresql - это дополнительный слой, аналога которому в mysql нет. Если вы сделаете в psql именно БД one и two то вы не сможете их быстро переключить, без переподключения к серверу и даже не сможете ни как в одном запросе использовать таблицы из двух БД. Так что вопрос скорее должен звучать "Зачем БД в psql" и ответ на него - для дополнительного разграничения рабочих пространств. Там где в Mysql вам пришлось бы разворачивать отдельный сервер в psql вы создаете БД

Comment: @Mike спасибо, стало чуток понятнее))

Comment: Посмотрите ещё на пользователей и права - станет ещё более непонятно.

Comment: В самом упрощенном варианте, то База Данных это набор Схем, а Схема это набор таблиц/представлений/функций